# Expected consultant bill given distribution of time taken

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The cdf of the number of hours it takes a consultant to complete a project is given by $F(x)= \dfrac{x^2}{16}$ for o to 4. The consultant bills $300 per hour, rounded up to the nearest half hour, for the project. What is the expected amount of the total bill?
>
> (a)900
> (b)800
> (c)872
> (d)950
> (e)1100

My work:

$f(x)= \dfrac{dF(x)}{dx}$

$f(x)=\dfrac{x}{8}$

so

integral of $x^2/8$ from 0 to 4 = $x^3/24$ from 0 to 4 = 64/24 = 2.6667

round 2.6667 to nearest half hour is 2.5

so

2.5*300 = 800

But that's wrong; the answer to the question is 872.

Can I please have help understanding why my method is incorrect, so I can try another method while understanding why my last attempt was incorrect.

Comment: I need this understanding, because otherwise I will not know which methods are appropriate for which problem. The solution guide wants to see a discrete approach. Is this the only viable method? This seems too tricky.

Comment: It seems to me that you have just ignored the part about rounding up to the nearest half hour. I would say that a discrete approach is necessary here.

Comment: I just didn't want to think that something so subtle could have such implications.

Comment: The probability distribution is continuous, but the cost is a step function.

Comment: How can you think that charging up to \$150 extra is _subtle_?

Comment: I had the rounding in the problem, i just forgot to use the rounded number. I made the edits. I have to have 2.5*300 =800 to get jebaited into the answer being 800 Thank you eyeballfrog!

Comment: Just for intuition: If you earn $10$% interest on $\$1000$, compounding annually, after $1$ year you'll have $\$1100$. If you compound interest continuously, you'll have $\$1000e^{.1} \approx \$1105.17$. There's a significant difference.

Comment: Wow, that's the answer I wanted Ted. That would get gold, if I have such powers. I forgot this part of accounting. I always wondered why we had to take accounting... I will remember the difference from compounding interest over time increments versus compounding continuously can have large implications (it should have been obvious and that's the thought I need to pass this f***er)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with compound interest!

Comment: @Jordan Your edit doesn't make sense.  $$2.5 \cdot 300 \neq 800$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it **gets rounded up to the nearest half hour**, the expected fee is simply

$$$150\left(\frac{0.5^2}{16}-\frac{0^2}{16}\right)+$300\left(\frac{1^2}{16}-\frac{0.5^2}{16}\right)+\cdots+$1200\left(\frac{4^2}{16}-\frac{3.5^2}{16}\right)$$

(the probability it lands in each half hour multiplied by the amount received in that half hour)

which is just $$$1200-$150\left(\frac{3.5^2}{16}+\cdots+\frac{0.5^2}{16}+\frac{0^2}{16}\right)=$871.875\approx$872$$

Comment: Why can't it be continuous? It's rounded... that's not doing it for me

Comment: @JordanGreenhut If the amount of time it takes is continuous, but the billing is done based on a rounded form of this time, then the amount billed is discrete, since the time associated to the bill is always some multiple of half an hour.

Comment: I can kinda see that. So time must be viewed as half hour increments, because that's the window the consultant offers their time. "Why wont continuous work?" is a better question

Comment: A continuous treatment of the problem without the rounding would work, but it would most likely give a different answer, unless all the rounding errors somehow cancel out.

Comment: @JordanGreenhut It is not forbidden to accept answers.

Comment: @JordanGreenhut See the comment above.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks friend!

Answer (score 4):

The problem here doesn't really have to do with discrete vs continuous. What you have done is to correctly calculate the expected *time* the project will take, **not** the expected *bill*. It is not correct to multiply the expected time by $300$ to get the expected bill, even if you round up that time.

Why is this? Let's say $X$ is the random variable representing the time taken, and $Y$ is the random variable representing the bill.
If the consultant did not round to the nearest half hour, then we would just have $Y=300X$.
In that case, you could have used the following (correct) reasoning:
$$\text{Since }Y=300X,\quad E[Y]=300E[X].$$

However, we actually have $Y=300\,\mathtt{rnd}(X)$, where $\mathtt{rnd}$ is the function that rounds up to the nearest half hour. Your method used the following (incorrect) reasoning:
$$\text{Since }Y=300\,\mathtt{rnd}(X),\quad E[Y]=300\,\mathtt{rnd}(E[X])\quad\color{red}{\text{False!}}$$
While expectation is linear, it does not commute with arbitrary functions (in this case the rounding function).
You have to compute the expectation of the $Y$ variable (the cost) directly, there is no way to get it just from the expectation of the $X$ variable (the time) - because the relationship between the two variables is more complicated than just a linear function.

P.S. The problem also says the time is rounded *up* to the nearest half hour, so your 2.66667 should have been rounded up to 3, not down to 2.5. That still wouldn't give the right answer for the reasons I explained above, but keep it in mind if you want to try the problem again.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the amount of the total bill, in dollars. Then $X$ is certainly a discrete random variable. Its possible values are $0, 150, 300, 450, \ldots, 1200$. To treat $X$ as a continuous random variable is an error, because it is simply not so.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a little

Answer (score 2):

The probability for the duration to be between $\frac{k-1}2$ and $\frac k2$ is $\frac{2k-1}{64}$ and the charge would be $150k$. Thus, the expected charge would be
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{75}{32}\sum_{k=1}^8\left(2k^2-k\right)
&=\frac{75}{32}\sum_{k=1}^8\left[4\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k}{1}\right]\\
&=\frac{75}{32}\left[4\binom{k+1}{3}+\binom{k+1}{2}\right]_{k=0}^{k=8}\\
&=\frac{75}{32}\left[4\binom{9}{3}+\binom{9}{2}\right]\\
&=\frac{75}{32}\cdot372\\[9pt]
&=871\tfrac78
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Fancy. Can you explain it further? How do you arrive at the left hand side equation?

Comment: $\frac{75}{32}\left(2k^2-k\right)=\frac{2k-1}{64}\cdot150k$ from the line above.

Comment: $\sum_k\binom{k}{n}=\binom{k+1}{n+1}$ follows from Pascal's recurrence: $\binom{k+1}{n+1}=\binom{k}{n+1}+\binom{k}{n}$